# Hibernate: many-to-many relationship table as entity

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

The question is in title:

*How can I make many-to-many relationship table as entity?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say, that your question is very reasonable. Take a look at this doc part: [Chapter 24. Best Practices](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/best-practices.html). An Extract:

> **Do not use exotic association mappings:**
>
> Practical test cases for real many-to-many associations are rare. Most
>   of the time you need additional information stored in the "link
>   table". In this case, it is much better to use two one-to-many
>   associations to an intermediate link class. In fact, most associations
>   are one-to-many and many-to-one. For this reason, you should proceed
>   cautiously when using any other association style.

The way, we are handling that, is by introducing the pairing object. So, if there is an `Employee` having many `Contacts`, we can have `EmployeeContact`. This way we can gain a lot, because we can enrich the EmployeeContact with more/new attributes (IsMain, IsActive etc.)

In this scenario, the mapping on both sides is that

- Employee has `one-to-many` (set) **EmployeeContacts**
- Contact has `one-to-many` (set) **EmployeeContacts**
- EmployeContact has `many-to-one` (relation) **Employee**
- EmployeContact has `many-to-one` (relation) **Contact**

So, at the end, the mapping is usual, but we can search for Employee or Contact using the Subqueries etc.

*NOTE: in that case is suitable, if the pairing table has its own surrogated key, e.g. EmployeeContactId. It could be added at any time.. e.g. with identity...*